# Alterar chave de assinatura de APK na PlayStore

Tags: android, ionic, google, google-play

Olá, tenho um app na Play Store da Google que era de outra conta e essa passou para minha conta, pois não vai mais mexer com ele e a cliente pediu para que nós trabalhássemos na próxima versão. O problema é o seguinte: quando vamos subir a nova APK ele pede que assinemos com a keystore da APK anterior, mas o outro dev não quer passar a keystore (faz sentido, já que é dele). Vi na documentação do Google que tem como colocarmos uma nova keystore para assinarmos com a nossa chave as próximas versões, mas não consegui entender muito bem como funciona esse processo de submeter a nova chave lá no painel de controle da Play Store. Caso alguém consiga explicar de outra forma ou disponibilizar algum material ficarei grato.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

passei por algo parecido a um tempo atras, eu perdi uma chave de um app meu. quando você perde a chave ou não possui coce pode abir um chamado na google. para isto siga os passos abaixo:

Etapa 1: gere uma nova chave privada e faça o upload do certificado
Para gerar uma nova chave de upload e fazer o registro dela, siga as instruções na Central de Ajuda do Android Studio. A nova chave precisa ser diferente da anterior.

Em seguida, exporte o certificado da nova chave para o formato PEM:

keytool -export -rfc -alias  -file  -keystore

Etapa 2: 
entre em contato com a equipe de suporte da google
Nossa equipe de suporte só aceita solicitações de redefinição de chaves quando elas são enviadas pelo proprietário da conta do Play Console.

Para entrar em contato com a nossa equipe, o proprietário da conta pode preencher este formulário. É preciso anexar o arquivo upload_certificate.pem.

Você receberá um e-mail quando a nova chave de upload for registrada. Depois disso, siga as etapas acima para atualizar o armazenamento de chaves e o registro no provedor da API.

informação disponível em: [Google](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423)

Comment: Acabei de fazer o formulário, agora tenho que esperar pra ver se dá certo. Agradecido pela atenção!

Comment: demora uns 3 dias para responderem. Depois é só subir o app já utilizando a nova chave.

Comment: Ainda bem que acionar o suporte funcionou, antigamente não tinha recurso.